# EF core - System.InvalidProgramException Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, identityserver4, ef-core-2.0

**Background**

1. The application uses identity server 4 and entity framework core 2.0.3.
2. It has been deployed in Azure web app using CI/CD via VSTS
3. It uses Azure SQL server.

**Problem**

I was notified by application insights that an exception has occurred due to which users are not able to login.I eventually resolved it by restarting the azure web-app.

I have been trying to reproduce the error in development but no luck. I have already gone through several posts including [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12242) and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/18323).

I am nervous because the error might reappear and again users won't be able to login. Kindly, guide me where should I start troubleshooting and how could I make sure this doesn't happen again.

Here the exception details. Fyi, I have never seen this exception before.

> An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'MyDbContext'.
>    System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
>    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__34.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<BufferlessMoveNext>d__10.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__9.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<FirstOrDefault_>d__165`1.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.d__7.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.<MoveNext>d__10.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.d__5.MoveNext()
>
> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
>    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__34.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<BufferlessMoveNext>d__10.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__9.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<FirstOrDefault_>d__165`1.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.d__7.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.<MoveNext>d__10.MoveNext()
>    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.d__5.MoveNext()
>
> **Call stack**: System.InvalidProgramException:
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen (System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection+d__34.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator+<BufferlessMoveNext>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy+<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator+<MoveNext>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+<FirstOrDefault_>d__165`1.MoveNext (System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.3000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1+Enumerator+<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2+d__7.MoveNext (System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.3000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+AsyncIterator`1+<MoveNext>d__10.MoveNext (System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.3000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider+ExceptionInterceptor`1+EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor+d__5.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like the issue reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311428/systeminvalidprogramexception-common-language-runt.html) which has a workaround.

> The temporary solution for this issue is to:
>
> 1) Determine the location of vsinstr.exe from the path added to the
>   Web.config file and delete vsinstr.exe
>
> 2) Rename vsinstr.legacy.exe to vsinstr.exe in the same directory
>
> 3) Rebuild your solution
>
> We have rolled back the change that caused this issue in the next
>   release of 15.9, so your applications should be running as normal
>   then.

Can you confirm whether this is the same issue you are seeing? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I have a different issue because my version is 15.7.3 and my solution builds just fine. Also, it is a .net core project which don't have web.config but there is one generated automatically in Azure web app and there is no reference to vsinstr.legacy.exe in it.